# How can we stop a repeated request for the same certificate in ADCS?

Tags: active-directory, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority, active-directory-adcs

If I submit the same CSR file twice to my Active Directory Certificate Services (online via the certsrv web interface), I am issued two different certificates (judging by the serial numbers).

Is there a way to configure ADCS to only allow a single certificate for a particular subject at a time? In other words, if AD already has a certificate for `foo.example.com` that hasn't been expired or revoked, and someone submits another CSR for `foo.example.com`, I want ADCS to either return the existing certificate or refuse to generate a new one.

There's an option on the certificate template called `[] Do not automatically reenroll if a duplicate certificate exists in Active Directory` that I thought would do this, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure ADCS to only allow a single certificate for a particular subject at a time?

no, there is no way to do this on CA side, it is not CA responsibility. If request passes all validation checks, it results in issued certificate.

> Do not automatically reenroll if a duplicate certificate exists in Active Directory

this setting is used exclusively by certificate autoenrollment component and used only for user encryption certificates that are published in AD.